# ImproperlyConfigured when installing django-sentry

Tags: django, installation, sentry

I installed Django Sentry following [these steps](http://maxlynch.com/blog/installing-sentry-and-raven-for-logging-in-django/), which works until I start the server and try to log in. If I submit any details (correct or not), I get

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Module "social_auth.backends.contrib.vkontakte" does not define a "VKontakteBackend" authentication backend
```

... in the console, the page itself just shows a formatted internal server error.

Is there a way to fix this (preferably without having to change Sentry code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade Sentry to (at least) 5.4.6 version

Comment: It's working now! I changed some other things as well, but I'll assume it was this. Thanks for the answer!